# How can I edit all nodes of thier dates at once?

Tags: nodes, datetime

Is there a module that allows me to change the dates of all nodes at once instead of doing it one by one thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could update the field in the db, much faster than node_loading and saving all the nodes with batch update etc.. backup db first.

Fields are:

```
node.created
node.changed
node_revision.timestamp (same as node changed)
```

e.g

```
$created = strtotime('2013-01-01 00:00:00');
$changed = REQUEST_TIME; // now

$query = db_update('node');
$query->fields(array('created' => $created, 'changed' => $changed));
$updated = $query->execute();

$query = db_update('node_revision');
$query->fields(array('timestamp' => $changed));
$updated = $query->execute();

drupal_flush_all_caches(); // clear cache
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through the Admin UI as I also like to show my clients how to do some functions. They usually don't know how to code...

Comment: If you want to try that way, you could do something with views_bulk_operations and either a default update operation, or a rules component to set the date value.